# Laravel OrderBy Errors with 5.8 Upgrade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

Having trouble with Laravel 5.8 because the orderBy commands stopped working. How would I rewrite these two areas of a controller so it stops throwing an error?

---

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $clients = Client::orderBy('identifier', 'name')->paginate(15);
    return view('admin.clients.index')->with('clients', $clients);
}
```

---

```
public function closed()
{
    $sortBy = 'name';
    $query = Client::onlyTrashed()->orderBy($sortBy, $sortBy == 'created_at' ? 'name' : 'asc')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'name');
    $projects = $query->get();
    return view('admin.clients.index')->with(['clients' => $projects, 'sortBy' => $sortBy]);
}
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you actually included the mentioned error

Answer (score 2):

> orderBy(string $column, string $direction = 'asc')

`orderBy` has two parameters, the second one is direction.
Before version 5.8, if the direction value you passed is not `asc`, it will automatically set `desc` as direction value:

```php
$this->{$this->unions ? 'unionOrders' : 'orders'}[] = [
            'column' => $column,
            'direction' => strtolower($direction) == 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc',
        ];
```

After Laravel 5.8+, if the direction value is not `asc` or `desc`, it will show the error:

```php
if (! in_array($direction, ['asc', 'desc'], true)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Order direction must be "asc" or "desc".');
        }
```

So if you want to order by two column, you can use two `orderBy`:

```php
$clients = Client::orderBy('identifier')->orderBy('name')->paginate(15);

# Raw SQL:
# select * from clients order by identifier asc, name asc
```